# SQL Spatial Indexing including category field(s)

Tags: sql, sql-server, spatial, spatial-query, sqlgeography

I have a spatial index set up on a geography field in my 2012 SQL database that stores item locations. There are about 15,000 Items.

I need to return a total of Items within a radius of N kilometres of a given Lat/Lng.

I can do this and it's fast.

```
DECLARE @radius GEOGRAPHY = GEOGRAPHY::Point(@Lat, @Lng, 4326).STBuffer(@RadiusInMetres*1000)

SELECT
COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM dbo.Items i
WHERE
i.LatLngGeo.STIntersects(@radius) = 1
```

However, what I now need to do is filter by several fields, to get items that match a given Category and Price.

```
DECLARE @radius GEOGRAPHY = GEOGRAPHY::Point(@Lat, @Lng, 4326).STBuffer(@RadiusInMetres*1000)

SELECT
COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM dbo.Items i
WHERE
i.LatLngGeo.STIntersects(@radius) = 1 AND
(i.Category = @Category OR @Category is null) AND
(i.Price < @Price OR @Price is null)
```

This grinds away for about 10+ seconds, and I can find no way of adding varchar or number fields to a spatial index.

What can I do to speed this up?

Comment: What does the query plan look like? Is it using the spatial index?

Answer (score 1):

I would start with something like this:

```
--Query 1 - use a CTE to split the two filters
DECLARE @radius GEOGRAPHY = GEOGRAPHY::Point(@Lat, @Lng, 4326).STBuffer(@RadiusInMetres * 1000);

WITH InRadius AS (
    SELECT * FROM dbo.Items WHERE LatLngGeo.STIntersects(@radius) = 1)
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    InRadius
WHERE
    ISNULL(@Category, Category) = Category
    AND ISNULL(@Price, Price) = Price;
GO
--Query 2 - use a temp table to *definitely( split the two filters
DECLARE @radius GEOGRAPHY = GEOGRAPHY::Point(@Lat, @Lng, 4326).STBuffer(@RadiusInMetres * 1000);

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #temp;
WITH InRadius AS (
    SELECT * FROM dbo.Items WHERE LatLngGeo.STIntersects(@radius) = 1)
SELECT * INTO #temp FROM InRadius;
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    #temp
WHERE
    ISNULL(@Category, Category) = Category
    AND ISNULL(@Price, Price) = Price;
```

Run those queries a few times, then benchmark them, compared to your original script.

Another trick is to copy your original query in as well, then view the execution plan.  What you are looking for is the percentage split per query, which would ideally be something like 98%:1%:1%, i.e. the original query will take 98% of the work, but it will probably look very different indeed.

If this doesn't help, and you are okay with temp tables, then try adding an index on the temp table that matches the criteria you are filtering for.  However, with only 15,00 rows the effect of an index should almost be imperceptible.

And finally, you could limit the data being loaded into the temp table to *only* be the items you are going to filter on, as all you seem to want is a count at the end?

Let's just take a quick recap:

- extract the data matching your spatial query (which you say is quick already);
- discard anything GEOGRAPHY based from the results, storing them in a temp table;
- index the temp table to speed up any filters;
- now your COUNT(*) should be just on a sub-set of the data (with no spatial data), and the optimiser will not be able to try and combine it with the proximity filter;
- profit!

Comment: I have tested both CTE and temp table queries on sql server 2019,  temp table idea works and split filters and has much better performance, but CTE idea does not work. CTE  generates almost the same plan as original query in the question.